# confusion of javascript closure

Tags: javascript

I am studying JavaScript closure.
I want to modularize with closure.
So I wrote the code and I did not get the results I wanted
I want different results for result box1 and box2. But for some reason getting same results.
what should I do?

```js
var spinBox = function() {
  var spinBoxConfig;

  return {
    create: function(config) { 
      spinBoxConfig = {
        value: typeof config.value === 'number' ? config.value : 200
      }
      return this;
    },
    getValue: function() {
      return spinBoxConfig.value;
    }
  }
}()
var box1 = spinBox.create({
  value: 30
});
var box2 = spinBox.create({
  value: 310
});

console.log(box1.getValue()); // same
console.log(box2.getValue()); // same
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The object containing `create` and `getValue` will only be created once. That’s why all `this` values point to this same object.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a closure once, when you define the spinbox object. Everything that calls create or getValue will be interacting with that single instance of spinBoxConfig. If you want to create brand new closures every time you call create, you'll need to do so in your create function.

```js
var spinBox = {
    create: function (config) {
       var spinBoxConfig = {
          value: typeof config.value === 'number' ? config.value : 200
       }

       return {
          getValue: function () {
              return spinBoxConfig.value;
          }
       }
    }
}

var box1 = spinBox.create({
  value: 30
});
var box2 = spinBox.create({
  value: 310
});

console.log(box1.getValue());
console.log(box2.getValue())
```

Though really, that spinBoxconfig is kind of overkill, since you already have the config param in your closure and it has all the relevant data. So you could do this:

```js
var spinBox = {
    create: function (config) {
       if (typeof config !== 'number') {
           config = 200;
       }

       return {
          getValue: function () {
              return config;
          }
       }
    }
}

var box1 = spinBox.create(30);
var box2 = spinBox.create(310);

console.log(box1.getValue());
console.log(box2.getValue())
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has been a great help to me.